# How is learning spells of certain levels restricted by available spellslots?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

For example, creating a Sorcerer 3/ Druid 2 character, who (as a level 5 multiclass character of entirely spell-casting classes) has four Lv1 spellslots, three Lv2 SSs and two Lv3 SSs. A level 3 sorcerer knows four sorcerer spells and would have four Lv1 SSs and two Lv2 SSs, so I would pick my sorcerer spells based on this. However, does this mean I can only learn two Lv2 sorcerer spells? Or can I learn three Lv2 sorcerer spells and a Lv1 sorcerer spell? Could I even just learn four Lv2 sorcerer spells if the Lv1 spells aren't appealing to me, even though I wouldn't be able to cast them all yet?

I understand you can only pick spells from a class spell list from as high a level as you have spellslots from that class (eg As Barbarian 11/ Sorcerer 9, you could pick sorcerer spells up to level 5), but not much else. The PHB just says you can learn class spells *"of a level for which you have spell slots"*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to remember, multiclassing is an exception to the normal rules. The rules in the multiclassing section override the rules under each individual class. In this case, the rule you are looking for is under the Spellcasting section of the multiclassing rules, on page 164 of the PHB:

> You determine what spells you know and can prepare for each class individually, as if you were a single-classed member of that class.

So when you are choosing your Sorcerer spells, you choose them as if you only had your Sorcerer levels. Your multiclass spell slots don't help you at all. So, your spells known go as follows:

- At Sorcerer 1, you choose 2 level 1 spells.
- At Sorcerer 2, you choose 1 more level 1 spell.
- At Sorcerer 3, you choose 1 more spell, which can be a level 1 spell or a level 2 spell.

You seem to be creating this character as if you gained all 3 Sorcerer levels at once, and that is adding to your confusion. As far as the rules are concerned, every character starts at level 1 and levels up one level at a time. If you are creating a character at a higher level, you should still start with a level 1 character and level it up one level at a time.